# Meaning of the value column in the elf symbol table

Tags: c, assembly, elf

I have an elf binary which has the following `dynsym` symbol table as output by `readelf`:

```
Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
 0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
 1: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.2.5 (2)
 2: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __gmon_start__
 3: 0000000000400440     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND printf@GLIBC_2.2.5 (2)
 4: 0000000000400460     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND fgets@GLIBC_2.2.5 (2)
```

What does the `value` column mean? Since this table has `400440` for `printf`, does that mean that the dynamic linker *has to* map `printf` at that address? If yes, how is this value decided? Is it random?

EDIT: Also, this is linux x86-64 with gcc

Comment: Is this binary statically linked? With a statically linked binary, I get no dynsym, but addresses that really seem to be the addresses that will be used during execution. With dynamic linking, I just get zeroes for all addresses.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy It's dynamically linked.

Comment: Ok, then I don't know. I just get zeroes in the dynsym table. Load it into gdb and see if the addresses match?

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy Yep, they do. `callq 400440`

Comment: It could be that this is the value of the corresponding PLT symbol.

Comment: @fuz Spot on, that's the value in the `.rela.plt` section. Cheers.

Comment: Very interesting. I just looked at some file created by GCC under Linux x86-64: All "UND" symbols in the dynamic symbol table have the value 0 in my file...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that the value of undefined dynamic symbols of function types is just the address of their entry in the PLT. Likewise, the values of entries for variables is probably just their entry in the GOT.